# How to reduce windows 10 alt-tab time?

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

I would like to reduce the time taken to **switch between applications using alt+tab in windows 10**. Currently it takes 0.5s to 1s (guesstimate), I would like it to be "instant" if possible (0.1s). My perceptions is that is is noticeably slower than windows 7 was even on an older, slower laptop, although I have not measured this directly (and an not sure how I would even make the measurement precisely.

I have disabled Focus Mode as suggested here: 
https://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-fix-slow-alt-plus-tab-when-playing-games-on-windows-10-april-2018-update-520927.shtml

Is there anything else I can do to increase alt-tab speed?

Comment: Its pretty instant on my windows 10 machine. I can only guess why it is slower on your end. Maybe you don't have enough memory, or you still use a traditional hdd instead of an SSD?

Comment: Maybe try [using old alt-tab dialogue](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/)